# how to cherry pick specific esbuild binaries when installing with yarn

Tags: node.js, vite, esbuild, yarn-v2

I'm installing vite react template, yarn stuck somewhere and when I check with `--verbose` I saw so many redundant packages installed like those.

```
verbose 3.383394574 Performing "GET" request to "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@esbuild/android-x64/-/android-x64-0.19.8.tgz".
verbose 3.412297881 Performing "GET" request to "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@esbuild/linux-arm/-/linux-arm-0.19.8.tgz".
verbose 3.4289958 Performing "GET" request to "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@esbuild/linux-mips64el/-/linux-mips64el-0.19.8.tgz".
verbose 3.438138307 Performing "GET" request to "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@esbuild/linux-ppc64/-/linux-ppc64-0.19.8.tgz".
verbose 3.442030601 Performing "GET" request to "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@esbuild/linux-x64/-/linux-x64-0.19.8.tgz".
verbose 3.449186704 Performing "GET" request to "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@esbuild/linux-loong64/-/linux-loong64-0.19.8.tgz".
verbose 3.461365038 Performing "GET" request to "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@esbuild/linux-s390x/-/linux-s390x-0.19.8.tgz".
verbose 3.471498568 Performing "GET" request to "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@esbuild/linux-riscv64/-/linux-riscv64-0.19.8.tgz".
verbose 35.782801854 Performing "GET" request to "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@esbuild/netbsd-x64/-/netbsd-x64-0.19.8.tgz".
verbose 40.800013747 Performing "GET" request to "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@esbuild/openbsd-x64/-/openbsd-x64-0.19.8.tgz".
verbose 51.831574917 Performing "GET" request to "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@esbuild/sunos-x64/-/sunos-x64-0.19.8.tgz".
verbose 59.994924433 Performing "GET" request to "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@esbuild/win32-arm64/-/win32-arm64-0.19.8.tgz".
```

Is there a way to only download `linux-x64` and `linux-x390x`?

my package.json is

```json
{
  "name": "app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.6",
    "wouter": "^2.12.1",
    "zustand": "^4.4.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.37",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.15",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.10.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.10.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint": "^8.53.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.4",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "vite": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```